# JAP: table column with name id but not primary key

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I have a table with the columns vendorid and id (and more, omitted here; using lombok for definition):

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "vendor_store")
public class VendorMeta {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "vendorid", unique = true)
  private String vendorid;

  @Column(name = "id", unique = false)
  private String id;
}
```

This is the corresponding repository:

```
@Repository
public interface VendorMetaRepository extends JpaRepository<VendorMeta, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<VendorMeta> {

  List<VendorMeta> findByVendorid(String vendorid);
}
```

I would expect that findByVendorid is returning a single element and findById returns a list, but it's working the opposite way:

Optional vendorMeta = vendorMetaRepository.findById("1");
List vendorMeta2 = vendorMetaRepository.findByVendorid("1");

Both methods return answers for searching vendorid, findbyId is also searching column vendorid.

What do I have to do to get the correct results?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not possible (at least when using lombok). The generated method findById() searches the primary key (whatever the name of this column is) and not the column with the name "id".

It is possible to use any column name for the primary key but not the name "id" for a non-primary-key column.